# Overriding a magento/module-sales view

Tags: magento2, overrides

**Brief**

I'd like to add a button on the Order Create screen. I know where the core file/line number is. Is there a way to extend this document somehow without having to override the whole file? It seems counterproductive to override a 260 line document for a couple of lines of code.

**File (line)**

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/items/grid.phtml

**Insert directly after this line**

```
<?php $block->getButtonHtml(__('Update Items and Quantities'), 'order.itemsUpdate()', 'action-secondary') ?>
```

Comment: Override the whole file

Comment: You have no other solution, than override the whole file.